# OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, error-handling, scikit-learn

I am trying to import the following libraries. I get an error message while importing sklearn . I believe it is related to DLL path but i am not able to rectify it . I don't want to manually specify any path in the code. Please help

Code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn import preprocessing
%matplotlib inline
```

Error :

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c2a7628c052c> in <module>
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      4 
----> 5 from sklearn import preprocessing
      6 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>
     62 else:
     63     from . import __check_build
---> 64     from .base import clone
     65     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     66 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in <module>
     10 
     11 import numpy as np
---> 12 from scipy import sparse
     13 from .externals import six
     14 from .utils.fixes import signature

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py in <module>
    102 
    103 # Allow distributors to run custom init code
--> 104 from . import _distributor_init
    105 
    106 __all__ += _num.__all__

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\_distributor_init.py in <module>
     59             os.chdir(libs_path)
     60             for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(libs_path, '*dll')):
---> 61                 WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
     62         finally:
     63             os.chdir(owd)

~\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    362 
    363         if handle is None:
--> 364             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    365         else:
    366             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Comment: Di you run your code via terminal or IDE? If you run your code in your terminal, make sure you have activated the environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try uninstalling scipy and then re-installing this particular verison. As it is stated in this particular github issue thread that there is a problem with the new release of scipy.

```
pip uninstall scipy
pip install scipy==1.4.1
```

https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/241